# get result of javascript function and post it as additional form data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have JS function that is basically

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething() {
        var s = 'some data'
        return s; }
</script>
```

and

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { data_to_send = x))
    {
       //some form controls that are sent to controller via model
    }
```

Is it possible, and how, to assign value returned by `doSomething` function to `x` variable in form?

I don't need x in my model, because it won't go to database. It's just some additional info from user, how to manipulate data in model before saving to database.

edit: Controller action is

```
public actionresult MyController(string data_to_Send, model) {}
```

Comment: you can assign the return of a function to a var easily like so: var myInfo = doSomething(); The rest of your question doesn't make a lot of sense to me the way it is worded.

Answer (score 0):

In the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.X1)
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.X2)
}
```

In the Model:

```
public class YourModel
{
  public string X1 { get; set; }
  public string X2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourModel model)
{
   string x1 = model.X1;
   string x2 = model.X2;
   return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form has to be posted in order to do what you are looking for. 
You can post the model along with *PostedDateValue*

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-field required">
                    <label for="Posted Data">Posted Data</label>
                    <input  id="txtPostedData" name="PostedDateValue" >
                    <input type="submit"  class="gradient" value="SUBMIT" />
                </div>
            }
)
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ActionMethod(string PostedDateValue)
        {
}
```